# ODI-1228: Task Load data-LKM SQL to Oracle- fails on the target > connection

Tags: oracle, plsql, etl, oracle-data-integrator

I'm working with Oracle Data Integrator inserting information from original source to temp table (BI_DSA.TMP_TABLE)

> ODI-1228: Task Load data-LKM SQL to Oracle- fails on the target
> connection BI_DSA. Caused By: java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
> ORA-12899: value too large for column
> "BI_DSA"."C$_0DELTA_TABLE"."FIELD" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)

I tried changing the lenght of 'FIELD' to more than 10 and reverse engineering but it didn't work.
Is this error coming from the original source? I'm doing a replica so I just have view privileges on it and I believe so because is the C$ table where the error comes from.

Thanks for the help!

**Solution: I tried with the length option before like the answers suggested but didn't work, I noticed the orginal source modified their field lenght so I reverse enginereed source table and problem solved.**

Greetings!

Comment: Could have something to do with byte and character semantics. FIELD could be set to 10 bytes and the value could be 10 characters with one a non-ascii character that takes 2 bytes so total of 11 bytes for 10 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bobby mentioned in the comment it might come from the byte/char semantics.

The C$ tables created by the LKMs usually copy the structure of the source data. So a workaround would be to go in the model and manually increase the size of the `FIELD` column in the source datastore (even if it doesn't represent what is in the database). The C$ table will be created whith that size on the next run.